What is this generic apple development certificate? What happens if expires?
this certificate is not present in my keychain (at least, so it seems to me).

I think it is just something used in development, on local machine, but since it is "generic" I'm confused.
I am distributing the app via private web site, I'm just afraid expiring could affect users somehow, a simple "development certificate" is not a profile, and it should be used only on a Mac for developing.
how can I discover what happens when it expires?

my app is present both on iOS and Macos
to be clear, I know it is not a "Mac certificate".
someone can help me?
here an image


I am distributing the app via private web site I don't get this line? Did you actually ship the app with a development certificate?

Please read tag descriptions before using the tag. Your question has nothing to do with statistical distributions.

@son yes, but the app is delivered via private association site. I create an .ipa file, then you install it. it should be called OTA installation.

In what way is it "generic"? And how can you not know what it is? You created it. And what is the point of showing us a screen shot with everything blacked out? And how are you currently codesigning?

App is not mine, and the developer account used is a mess, a lot of expired certificates. Expired and valid ones on different machines, some of which very old. About genric, is not related to ios or mac, others are. The blacked out stripes are there clearly for privacy concerns, preserve original developer name is obiouvsly the point. But you can see the situation I’m facing.

Distribution cert is what you use to sign an app for production in most cases. Development cert is used for building/developing apps and testing.
First check which cert is being used to sign your ipa

Unzips the ipa which creates a Payload folder
unzip -q <your_app>.ipa
Extract contents of the embeded profile to a plist file
security cms -D -i Payload/<your_app>.app/embedded.mobileprovision > <your_app>.plist
Get the name of the cert being used
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print Name" <your_app>.plist
Can also get the expiration date
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print ExpirationDate" <your_app>.plist

Depending on the outcome of above, can decide whether the Development cert is needed or not.

how can I discover what happens when it expires?

You would need to re-sign your ipa if this happens
